# How do I refresh the current page after adding an item to the cart in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I need to refresh the current page after a customer adds an item to the shopping cart in magento. How do I do this?

Comment: As I see it you want an AJAX cart right ? correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If adding items to your cart through the use of javascript/ajax

```
location.reload();
```

If adding items to your cart with PHP, and are directing to another page to process the addition, just redirect page to the page they came from.

```
$page =  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("location:$page");
```